# SocketException & IOException when opening new instances of an already running single instance application

Tags: c++, winforms, clr

I'm working on an CLR C++ project, it works properly when running single instace.
However when i debug run the program from visual studio and then run the compiled executable from the project debug folder i get `Socket` and `IO` exceptions, the application doesn't crash and it keeps running normally.

I'm using the following class to enable single instance:

#### initializer.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Project2
{
    public ref class SingleApplication: public Microsoft::VisualBasic::ApplicationServices::WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
    protected:
        virtual void OnCreateMainForm() override;

    protected:
        ~SingleApplication ()
        {
        }

    public:
        SingleApplication (void);
        System::Void StartNextInstance (System::Object ^sender, Microsoft::VisualBasic::ApplicationServices::StartupNextInstanceEventArgs ^e);
    };
}
```

#### initializer.cpp

```
#include "initializer.h"
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace Project2;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualBasic::ApplicationServices;

SingleApplication::SingleApplication (void)
{
    this->IsSingleInstance = true;
    this->EnableVisualStyles = true;
    this->StartupNextInstance += gcnew
        StartupNextInstanceEventHandler (this, &SingleApplication::StartNextInstance);
}

Void SingleApplication::StartNextInstance (Object ^sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs ^e)
{
    MyForm ^form = safe_cast<MyForm ^> (this->MainForm);

    if (form->IsMinimizedToSystemTray()) form->MakeVisible();
    else if (form->WindowState == FormWindowState::Minimized)
    {
        form->Show();
        form->WindowState = FormWindowState::Normal;
    }
    else form->BringToFront();

    form->Focus();
}

void SingleApplication::OnCreateMainForm()
{
    this->MainForm = gcnew MyForm();
}
```

#### Entry Point:

```
[STAThread]
int main (array<String ^> ^argv)
{
    SingleApplication ^MyApplication = gcnew SingleApplication();
    MyApplication->Run (argv);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Debug log:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
```

After enabling break on exceptions i got these details:

1.SocketException:

```
Additional information: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

2.IOException:

```
Additional information: The read operation failed, see inner exception.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

What's causing these exceptions and how can handle them?

Answer (score -1):

I think your visual studio debugger is still running basically not terminating properly, it could be that you may still have a thread running in the background that is holding the socket open.